# Given an index label, how would you extract the index position in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

New to python, trying to take a csv and get the country that has the max number of gold medals. I can get the country name as a type Index but need a string value for the submission.

---

*csv has rows of countries as the indices, and columns with stats.*

`ind = DataFrame.index.get_loc(index_result)` doesn't work because it doesn't have a valid key.

If I run `dataframe.loc[ind]`, it returns the entire row.

---

```
df = read_csv('csv', index_col=0,skiprows=1)

for loop to get the most gold medals:
   mostMedals= iterator

getIndex = (df[df['medals' == mostMedals]).index #check the column medals 
                       #for mostMedals cell to see what country won that many

ind = dataframe.index.get_loc[getIndex] #doesn't like the key
```

What I'm going for is to get the index position of the `getIndex` so I can run something like `dataframe.index[getIndex]` and that will give me the string I need but I can't figure out how to get that index position integer.

Comment: seems like you could max or sum to get the "most" medals rather than a brute force iteration. You will benefit from exploring pandas documentation and learn some other handy methods to use! Can you update your question with [mcve] perhaps by including example dataframe (e.g., print `df.head()`) and then illustrate what the expected results.

Comment: `list(df.where(df['medals'] == mostMedals).dropna().index)` will give you a list of all country(s) which have `df['medals'] == mostMedals`.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. Didn't get to the where attribute yet. Max is much easier than what I was doing too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comments above, this is how I would approach it. There may be better/other ways, pandas is a pretty enormous library with lots of neat functionality that I don't know yet, either!

```
df = read_csv('csv', index_col=0,skiprows=1)
max_medals = df['medals'].max()
countries = list(df.where(df['medals'] == max_medals).dropna().index)
```

Unpacking that expression, the `where` method returns a frame based on df that matches the *condition* expressed. `dropna()` tells us to remove any rows that are NaN values, and `index` returns the remaining row index. Finally, I wrap that all in `list`, which isn't strictly necessary but I prefer working with simple built-in types unless I have a greater need.